# Multiplying Integrals with Different Bounds

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

The question I have is two integrals mutliplied with different bounds

> $$\alpha_0(x)=\int_x^1\exp\left(\frac{-\varphi\lambda^2}2\right)d\lambda\cdot\left(\int_0^1\exp\left(\frac{-\varphi\lambda^2}2\right)d\lambda\right)$$

What I would like to do is differentiate this with respect to $x$, but am not sure how to do so considering that I have the two integrals multiplied by eachother.

What is f '(alpha0(x))

I understand that the problem would be simple if they were added/subtracted.

I understand from the Fundamental Law of Calculus that the $x$ will replace the $\lambda$ when I differentiate a single integral, just not sure how to approach with the double integral.

I know that an analytical solution is definitely possible.

Thank you.

Comment: See that the term in brackets is a constant, since the bounds of integration are constant. You need only to differentiate the leftmost integral.

Comment: Just one of the integrals depends on $x$. The other one is a constant. So proceed with the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus; be sure to account for the fact that the variable is the lower limit of integration. (I have just reprased @rafa11111 's comment, which you seem to have ignored.)